# How can below template class be generalized to call any function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, methods, lambda

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template<typename... Args>
class Listner {
public:
    template<typename T>
    void attachListner(T *t) {
        m_listenerCallbacks.insert(std::make_pair(reinterpret_cast<void*>(t), [&t](Args... args){t->callback(args...); }));
    }

    template<typename T>
    void detachListner(T *t) {
        m_listenerCallbacks.erase(reinterpret_cast<void*>(t));
    }

    void notify(Args... args) {
        for (auto l : m_listenerCallbacks)
            l.second(args...);
    }
private:
    std::map<void*, std::function<void(Args...)>> m_listenerCallbacks;
};
```

Using above `Listner` class I am able to register objects which has a public method named `callback`. Is it possible to generalize `Listner` class in such a way that the method name (`callback`) can also passed as template argument.

Comment: No, so use `operator()` instead (e.g., `for (auto l : m_listenerCallbacks) l(args...);`). This also allows you to pass lambdas and function pointers as listeners.

Comment: Try to understand how this works: https://github.com/klmr/multifunction it may even be what you want

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution based on the example code that might work for you:

```
#include <map>
#include <functional>

template<typename>
struct Listner;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Listner<R(Args...)> {
    template<typename T, R(T::*M)(Args...) = &T::callback>
    void attachListner(T *t) {
        m_listenerCallbacks.insert(std::make_pair(static_cast<void*>(t), [t](Args... args){ (t->*M)(args...); }));
    }

    void notify(Args... args) {
        for (auto l : m_listenerCallbacks)
            l.second(args...);
    }

private:
    std::map<void*, std::function<void(Args...)>> m_listenerCallbacks;
};

struct A {
    void f(int, char) {}
    void f(int, double) {}
    void f(int) {}
};

int main() {
    A a;
    Listner<void(int, char)> l;
    l.attachListner<A, &A::f>(&a);
    l.notify(0, 'c');
}
```

The basic idea is that you must specify the function type entirely (see `Listner<void(int, char)>`). The sole parameters list isn't enough.
We can do it with a partial specialization of a class template as:

```
template<typename>
struct Listner;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct Listner<R(Args...)> {
    // ...
};
```

Once you did it, we can use that type to detect the right overload as a template parameter:

```
template<typename T, R(T::*M)(Args...) = &T::callback>
void attachListner(T *t) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that I put a default (`&T::callback`) so that you can invoke it either as:

```
l.attachListner<A, &A::f>(&a);
```

If you want to use a different member function, or as:

```
l.attachListner(&a);
```

If `A` has a member method named `callback` and you want to use it as it was before.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I **strongly** suggest to pass the `t` pointers by value, not by reference to the lambda function; so

```
m_listenerCallbacks.insert(
   std::make_pair(reinterpret_cast<void*>(t),i
                  [=](Args... args){t->callback(args...); }));
// ----------------^ (not &)
```

Anyway...

> Is it possible to generalize Listner class in such a way that the method name (callback) can also passed as template argument.

As template argument for the class of for the `attachListner()` method?

In first case, the best (?) I can imagine is a dirty C-macro like based solution (I know... C-macro are distilled evil... but sometimes...).

In the following example, suppose you want a `Listner` that call the `bar()` method in all the object registered; you have to call the `Listner` macro as follows

```
Listner(bar);
```

This create a `Listner_bar` template class that can be used as follows

```
Listner_bar<int, std::string const &> l;
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

#define Listner(foo)                                                     \
                                                                         \
template <typename ... Args>                                             \
class Listner_##foo                                                      \
 {                                                                       \
   public:                                                               \
      template <typename T>                                              \
      void attachListner (T * t)                                         \
       { m_listenerCallbacks[reinterpret_cast<void*>(t)]                 \
            = [=](Args... args){(t->*(&T::foo))(args...);}; }            \
                                                                         \
      template <typename T>                                              \
      void detachListner (T * t)                                         \
       { m_listenerCallbacks.erase(reinterpret_cast<void*>(t)); }        \
                                                                         \
      void notify (Args ... args)                                        \
       { for (auto const & l : m_listenerCallbacks) l.second(args...); } \
                                                                         \
   private:                                                              \
      std::map<void*, std::function<void(Args...)>> m_listenerCallbacks; \
 }

struct A
 {
   void bar (int i, std::string const & s)
    { std::cout << "A::bar - " << i << ", " << s << std::endl; }
 };

struct B
 {
   void bar (int i, std::string const & s)
    { std::cout << "B::bar - " << i << ", " << s << std::endl; }
 };

Listner(bar);

int main ()
 {
   Listner_bar<int, std::string const &> l;

   A a;
   B b;

   l.attachListner(&a);
   l.attachListner(&b);

   l.notify(1, "one");

   l.detachListner(&a);

   l.notify(2, "two");
 }
```

If you want that the method name is passed as template argument to `attachListner()` (so different names for different objects)... not exactly what you want, I suppose, but the best I can imagine is pass pointer method to `attachListner()` (without C-style macros, this time); something like

```
l.attachListner(&a, &A::foo);
```

where `a` is an object of type `A` and you want call it's `foo()` method.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename ... Args>
class Listner
 {
   public:
      template <typename T, typename M>
      void attachListner (T * t, M m)
       { m_listenerCallbacks[reinterpret_cast<void*>(t)]
            = [=](Args... args){(t->*m)(args...);}; }

      template <typename T>
      void detachListner (T * t)
       { m_listenerCallbacks.erase(reinterpret_cast<void*>(t)); }

      void notify (Args ... args)
       { for (auto const & l : m_listenerCallbacks) l.second(args...); }

   private:
      std::map<void*, std::function<void(Args...)>> m_listenerCallbacks;
 };

struct A
 {
   void foo (int i, std::string const & s)
    { std::cout << "A::foo - " << i << ", " << s << std::endl; }
 };

struct B
 {
   void bar (int i, std::string const & s)
    { std::cout << "B::bar - " << i << ", " << s << std::endl; }
 };


int main ()
 {
   Listner<int, std::string const &> l;

   A a;
   B b;

   l.attachListner(&a, &A::foo);
   l.attachListner(&b, &B::bar);

   l.notify(1, "one");

   l.detachListner(&a);

   l.notify(2, "two");
 }
```

**-- EDIT --** As pointed by skypjack, the second solution work if the method called aren't overloaded. The skypjack answer propose a way to solve this problem.

Comment: The last example won't work if you have overloaded methods in `A` or `B`.

Comment: @max66: Thank you, your first example gives me the desired behavior but I was wondering if similar behavior can be achieved without macro or without passing the actual function pointer. Not sure if it is even possible. May I also ask why you strongly suggest that I should have passed  `t` as value not as reference.

Comment: @skypjack - unfortunately you're right; answer modified to indicate this problem

Comment: @Sajal - I don't say it's impossible (without macro or without passing the actual function pointer) but, if possible, I don't know how. Regarding the question about value/reference, take in count that `t` is a temporary variable in `attachListner()`; if you memorize, in the lambda, a reference to it, when you use it (`notify()`), the original `t` doesn't exit anymore; so the `t` value in the lambda is undefined; so undefined is the behavior of the program. with my clang++ I get a  "core dump". You should, in the lambda, memorize the **value** of `t`, so you can avoid this problem.

Comment: @max66 - Thank you for your answer regarding why `t` should be passed as value here. I could the observe the problem while trying out a use-case.